# Properties of a string class in C++

Tags: c++, string

I am working through C++ program design by Cohoon and Davidson. This is what it says about string class attributes (3rd Edition, Page 123):

- Characters that comprise the string
- The number of characters in the string

My question is: If we know the characters in the string, does not it implies we already know about number of characters in the string? What is the need to explicitly specify the second attribute?

Comment: Calling string::length() doesn't need to explicitly count the characters every time.

Comment: As far as it's concerned (at least in C++03, where it is not required to be null-terminated), without a size, it could be holding `"hello worldsisiofhodifjsdpfojdspofjposdfjsd"`. The point is that without a size, you *need* a terminating sequence, and without a terminating sequence, you *need* a size.

Comment: @chris the constraints on `c_str()` mean that most likely `std::string` will be internally null terminated (or maintain a completely parallel null term. string).

Comment: This is not actually a question about the string class.  It is a question about why some particular authors used some particular words.  Vote to close.

Comment: @ David: So are these attributes of string class unique to the book I am following? These are not universal attributes?

Comment: They are universal.  Every string has some characters.  Every string has a length.  I didn't say how the length is computed. What behavior of the string class are you actually wondering about?  Do you have a question that can be answered objectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If we know the characters in the string, does not it implies we already know about number of characters in the string?

Well in C we know the number of elements because we can count up to the NULL terminal. But think how expensive it is to get the length of a string? It takes walking the entire string. For such a common operation, why wouldn't we want this to be a constant-time operation?

Comment: Are you saying that in memory locations, there are characters of the string are saved and in one memory location, only the length of the string is saved and whenever I use the expression StringName.size(), it goes to memory location where length is stored and outputs that value.

Answer (score 1):

You are right but length is required in many places like counting, or knowing the length/end of malloc memory so it is better to store length as additional property to make your program run fast.

Consider what will happen if the program needs to count the chars all the way just to tell you how many are there in it. Moreover when this feature is accessed frequently.

So it simply saves time storing length too.

So all actual implementations of string classes do store length of the string.